# jQuery .html() anonymous function return oldHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/ZnMF5/1/

This is obviously some lack of understanding on my part, but I am trying to run an anonymous function with `.html()` to do some custom code and then return the old html string value to a variable. It isn't returning the html as I would expect but is returning a jQuery object based on the selector I used.

```
var oldHtml = $('#test').html(function(index, oldHtml){
    //some custom code here
    return oldHtml;
});
console.log(oldHtml);
```

I thought I could return the html this way as it works in a normal function call.

```
var someOtherHtml = getOldHtml();

console.log(someOtherHtml);

function getOldHtml(){
    return $('#test').html();
}
```

What am I not understanding about jQuery when it comes to this?

Comment: Your anonymous function return value is being used as an html() parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(...).html(function)` returns the original jQuery object, not the html in the selected element.

What you return in the function is actually set as the new html of the selected element.

```
$(collection).html(function(){
    return "I'm the new html!";
});
// results in all elements in collection receiving the html ("I'm the new html!")
// equivalent to:
// $(collection).html("I'm the new html!");
```

Comment: So is the return statement ignored?

Answer (score 0):

```
var cacheOldHtml = '';
$('#test').html(function(index, oldHtml){
    //some custom code here
    cacheOldHtml = oldHtml;
});
```

If you want to change the HTML content of `#test` you could do:

```
$('#test').html(function(index, oldHtml){
    //some custom code here
    var newHtml = oldHtml + '<div>NEW</div>';
    return newHtml;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var oldHtml` will technically refer `$('#test')` object.

The syntax that you are using  will set the `html` of the element to `oldHtml` and assign the jQueryObject to `oldHtml`

Answer (score 0):

You could just

```
var oldHtml = $('#test').html();
//custom code
$("#test").html(customHtml);
```

---

The function returns to jQuery internals. Consider:

```
function jQueryInternal(fn) {
    var theFunctionReturned = fn();
    //do something with e.g. 3
    return 4; //This is what is separately returned to the calling code
}
```

Meanwhile, in completely different place:

```
//Here are surroundings completely unaffected by the return value
jQueryInternal(function() {
    return 3; //Return 3 to the jQueryInternal function
          //it doesn't do anything to the surrounding code
});
//Here are surroundings completely unaffected by the return value
```

---

The jQuery internals don't ignore the return value, see http://jsfiddle.net/B7Htd/